# How to Send Location information periodically (Ex -15minutes) to php server from BlackBerry?

Tags: php, blackberry, location

I am newbie to Blackberry development. I wanted to know the procedure for receiving & sending location data periodically to php server from a Blackberry application. How can I implement it? Any suggestions, link or code examples will be really helpful for me.

Comment: you want to send lat and lang to your server? rare you using web service? please provide me some more data...

Comment: Yes i wanted to send location information to the php server. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution with code....

```
public class GetLatLon {
private LocationProvider provider,_locationProvider;
public static Timer timer;
double longitude=0.0,lattitude=0.0;
Criteria criteria;
public String number;
public GetLatLon(final int duration)//Pass duration in constructor of this class as your periodically time interval

    timer = new Timer();
    this.duration=duration;
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {                    
        public void run() {
        startLocationUpdate(duration);
        }
    }, 0, duration*60*1000);   
}

public  class LocationListenerImpl implements LocationListener {
    public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, final Location location) {
        System.out.println("---Location Updated-----");
        if (location.isValid()) {
            System.out.println("---Location Valid----");
                    longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
                    lattitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
                    System.out.println("Lattitude :-=============================="+lattitude);
                    System.out.println("Longitude :-=============================="+longitude);
                                        //Here you will call your webservice to put data onto the php server.
                    _locationProvider.setLocationListener(null, 0, 0, 0);
            }else{
            System.out.println("else NOT valid--Cellsite valide=-----");
            setupCriteria();
            setupProvider();
        }
        System.out.println("---Location Not Valid----");
    }
    public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) {}
}

private void setupCriteria() {
    criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
}


private void setupProvider() {
    try {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
           System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
        provider.setLocationListener(
                new LocationListenerImpl(), 1, 1, 1);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.toString());
    }
}
public void startLocationUpdate() 
{
    try{
        _locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
        if (_locationProvider != null) {
            _locationProvider.setLocationListener(
                    new LocationListenerImpl(), 1, 1, 1);
        } 
    }catch(LocationException le){
        System.out.println("----Exception Of Location--"+le);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks For your warm help but i wanted to Post this info to php server how can i don that?

Comment: I mean, i want to store those information to mysql database using php script. how can i do that?